# How to reset DefaultAudience when Logging Out from FB on Android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm using FB SDK to connect my App to FB. When I run the app for the first time on a particular device, when I execute the following code:

```
LoginManager.getInstance.logInWithReadPermissions()
LoginManager.getInstance.logInWithPublishPermissions()
```

The user is taken to the FB Android App and is asked if my App should be given certain user accesses. For publish permissions, the user is also given a choice to specify who should see the published content (only_me, friends, everyone, etc...)

I logout from FB via

```
LoginManager.getInstance.logout()
```

When I attempt to login again, from the same device, the App is simply connected to FB, without asking if the App should be given by FB various permissions. How can I force FB to ask the user about various login permissions upon every login. In particular, I want the user to be able to change who gets to see the published content.

I know that I can changed who gets to see the published content via

```
LoginManager.getInstance.setDefaultAudience()
```

but then, I'd have to keep track of the FB audience setting in my App.